# VB.NET WCF - Error Using my function

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a function to get information on a SQL Server Table. I know the function is correct and returning everything as suposed too (I used msgBox to check it). The problem is when I try to use that function it displays an error:

[image]

My WCF Function:

```
    Public Function GetCLInfo(ByVal cl_ID As Integer) Implements SQLOperator.GetCLInfo
    Dim CLInfo(7) As String
    Try
        SQLCon.ConnectionString = SQLConString
        SQLCon.Open()

        SQLCMD = New SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.cl Where ID=" & cl_ID & ";", SQLCon)
        SQLDataReader = SQLCMD.ExecuteReader()

        While SQLDataReader.Read
            CLInfo(0) = SQLDataReader("ID")
            CLInfo(1) = SQLDataReader("Name")
            CLInfo(2) = SQLDataReader("Address")
            CLInfo(3) = SQLDataReader("Contact")
        End While

        Return CLInfo
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & Environment.NewLine & ex.ToString)
        CLInfo(0) = "False"
        Return CLInfo
    Finally
        SQLCon.Close()
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try

    Return CLInfo
End Function
```

In the picture you can see aswell how I'm trying to use the function.

Can someone kindly tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function doesn't specify what the return type is. Do you have `Option Strict On`?

Comment: Option Strict On? Sorry for my ignorance but I do not know what that is. I tried declaring the function specifying the return type. I used Public Function GetCLInfo(ByVal cl_ID As Integer) As String() .... Still did not worked!

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/what-do-option-strict-and-option-explicit-do

Comment: Option Strick On or Off and Option Explict On or Off did not help. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are calling a function to return string array and program doesn't catch by itself. As @Matt Wilko point out use `Option Strict On`.
Second if you have more than one client your logic fails.

```
For I as integer = 1 to AllCl
Dim cl(7) as String
cl = Service.GetClInfo(I)
next
```

Above code will reset every each time, plus when you leave for loop you are loosing access to cl.

Ugly fix could be `multidimensional array`.

Now you should specify your return type

```
Public Function GetCLInfo(ByVal cl_ID As Integer) As String() Implements SQLOperator.GetCLInfo
```